# Funcion js que asigne el height div

Tags: javascript

Amigos alguien me puede ayudar, estoy atascado en esto (manejo poco o nada el tema) 
Como hacer una funcion que le asigne el height a un div a partir del height de una imagen hija + 10px o %. aca mi borrador [ver borrador](https://jsfiddle.net/twze063b/1/)
Agradezo la ayuda 
Postdata la posicion de la imagen debe ser absoluta (no puede ser otra)

**Código agregado:**

```js
function myFunction() {
   var alto = document.getElementById("pic").style.height;
   }
   //funcion que asigne al id #bigPic la altura de la imagen #pic + 10px o 10% al cargar la pagina 
/* Es decir que el div que contiene la imagen la alura se la de la imagen mas unos pixeles o % de mas */
```

```css
.color1 { background:red; }
.color2 { background:green; }
#bigPic img {
 width: 80%;
  height:auto;
 top: 10%;
 left: 10%;
 position: absolute;
}
#bigPic {
 background: #F7A3A4;
  width: 90%;
  position:relative;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid text-center">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-8 color1">
  <div id="bigPic"> <!-- div al que debo asignarle la altura-->
    <img id="pic" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/250/"  alt="" /> <!-- img donde tomo la medida-->
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 color1">.col-md-4</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8 color2">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 color2">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con tu misma función, prueba esto:

```
function myFunction() {
   var alto = document.getElementById("pic").style.height;
   document.getElementById("bigPic").style.height = (alto + tuAumento).toString();
}
```

Así cunado se ejecute tu función, debería cambiarte el height de bigPic.
No estoy seguro si hay que pasarlo a string pero si así no te funciona prueba dejándolo así:

```
document.getElementById("bigPic").style.height = alto + tuAumento;
```

Comment: Amigo gracias por responder, la cargo en el `body onload="myFunction()" `pero no me funciona, algo debo estar haciendo mal

Comment: Ninguna de las dos formas??

Comment: lastimosamente no me funciona. :( inlcuso le quite el tuAmuento para que la altura fuera igual a la de la iamgen no importa que quedara cortada, para ver si funcionaba pero nada. https://jsfiddle.net/twze063b/3/

Comment: Me salvarias de este problemas si me ayudas a solucinarla, yo no doy con el problema

Comment: puedes tener algun estilo que te lo machaque? porque es la unica idea que tengo, porque se debería poder asi